# `/s` for multiline for variable regular expression `qr//`

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to match and extract the first (path like) word and the very last word in a multiline string (text = shell prompt + command + output). I have a working regular expression

```
perl -le 'print "$1/$2" if "~/src\nfind\nboards.txt" =~ m`([/~]\S+).*?(\S+)\s*$`s'
# returns expected ~/src/boards.txt
```

(https://regex101.com/r/uB4kN1/4 for nicer illustration)

But I run into problems when I try to use a variable regular expression.

```
echo '([/~]\S+).*?(\S+)\s*$' | 
  perl -lne '$reg=qr/$_/; 
             print "$1/$2" if "~/src\nfind\nboards.txt" =~ /$reg/s';
```

Comment: I thought `/$reg/s` should just add `//s` to the global flags after interpolation. Anyway, `/$_/s' probably works, have you tried it ?

Comment: I presented the question poorly. In the actual code, the regex is user provided and the text to match is the output of `xclip -o`.  There, I was having a hard time using /$reg/ directly, hence the qr//. https://github.com/WillForan/plum/blob/master/plum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `/s` single-string option should be provided at `qr//` not in the `=~ //` comparison

```
echo '([/~]\S+).*?(\S+)\s*$' | 
 perl -lne '$reg=qr/$_/s;  # < HERE
            print "$1/$2" 
              if "~/src\nfind\nboards.txt" =~ /$reg/';
            #                               NOT HERE^
```